# batch update using jdbcTemplate in spring

Tags: java, spring, hashmap, jdbctemplate, batch-updates

i have seen the code for batch update like the below one using ArrayList :

```
@Override
public void saveBatch(final List<Employee> employeeList) {
    final int batchSize = 500;

    for (int j = 0; j < employeeList.size(); j += batchSize) {

        final List<Employee> batchList = employeeList.subList(j, j + batchSize > employeeList.size() ? employeeList.size() : j + batchSize);

        getJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate(QUERY_SAVE,
            new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
                @Override
                public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i)
                        throws SQLException {
                    Employee employee = batchList.get(i);
                    ps.setString(1, employee.getFirstname());
                    ps.setString(2, employee.getLastname());
                    ps.setString(3, employee.getEmployeeIdOnSourceSystem());
                }

                @Override
                public int getBatchSize() {
                    return batchList.size();
                }
            });

    }
}
```

but if I use Hashmap like the below : `HashMap<String, VerifyPaymentRO> verifyPaymentInfoMap`

`VerifyPaymentRO` is java bean

how do I use it for updating the record ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create `List<?>` out from the map values and you can use the same code you have posted:

```
List<VerifyPaymentRO> verifyPaymentList = new ArrayList<>(verifyPaymentInfoMap.values());
```

Comment: It worked fine as I expected, now how do I return the status like whether the update is done or failed?? +1 for your post thanks.

Comment: Well if it fails, a runtime exception will be thrown. If you want to skip failed batches, then you also need to care about your transaction handling (i.e. each batch should run in its own transaction so that it can be rolled back - check `TransactionTemplate` and `REQUIRES_NEW` propagation).